# Read bluetooth pulse on Android

Tags: bluetooth, monitor, rate

I'm trying to read the pulse of a heart rate monitor bluetooth. Now I connect the device via Bluetooth and see their name, status, etc., but do not know how to read pulses.
I have read that it was easier by smartgattlib library, but neither him. Someone could tell me how or made used the library to read a device smartgattlib?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android you need to subscribe for notifications on the pulse characteristic.

Please check the bluetooth low energy sample: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt

On the sample after subscribing for notifications onCharacteristicChanged() callback will be called, you will need to read the pulse data there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use library but before use that, get the detail documentation of heart rate monitor (What all services it host and what all characteristic it has). After knowing the device properties, you can read and write those characteristic. Hope it will help !!!

[Sensor Tag](https://github.com/StevenRudenko/BleSensorTag)

[IBM blueMix](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/iot-sensor-tag)